# <b-form-select-> v-model change isn't reflected in the selected value

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

So i have a b-form-select with a v-model i need to change dynamically my issue is when i change the v-model to another element of the list the :options are taken from the selected value doesn't change

Code example :

```
   <b-form-select :options="ListA" v-model="Depart" value-field="Livreur" text-field="Livreur"></b-form-select>
        data(){
         Depart:'',
         ListA:[],
    }
my method is simply :
function(){
   this.Depart = this.ListA[0]
}
```

the list is structured as such :

this.ListA.push({Livreur:"example",id:0})

as far as i know it should change the selected value of the b-form-select but instead nothing at all happens , any ideas ? thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your `value-field` should probably be `id` not `Livreur`, except if `Livreur` is a unique identifier as well.

Relevant part in the documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#changing-the-option-field-names

`this.Depart` should also not be an object, but the value of the identifier you chose in the `value-field` property. In your case it should be:

if `value-field` is `id`:

```
this.Depart = this.ListA[0].id
```

if `value-field` is `Livreur`:

```
this.Depart = this.ListA[0].Livreur
```

Comment: i'm new to vuejs overall so execuse my lack of knowledge but since in my case the value and text are the same i thought i can set them both to have the same value ?

Comment: Yes. You probably can use the same property for text and value, as long as they are unique. My assumption was that `id` would be the unique identifier here. I'll edit my answer and also why your model isn't working

Comment: If you really want to keep the text and value the same, you can just make options an array of strings instead of an array of objects. E.g. `this.ListA.push('example'); this.Depart = 'example';`

Comment: you had it on the nose, indeed i didn't know this was a requirement all i had to do was seperate the two fields and voila its working, Thank you so much kind stranger